.Net MAUI Web authenticator using Azure Functions as Backend
I'm following this example for .NET MAUI Web authenticator to integrate google authentication in my .NET MAUI app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-9.0&tabs=android
This example uses a .NET Web API as the backend. I wish to use Azure Functions as my backend. How can I achieve this?
I've looked but there are not any examples. I do not wish to use MSAL.
EDIT: I know Azure Functions and App Services offer this option
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization
But there are no examples on how to integrate this approach with .NET MAUI web authenticator

Ok. I've got something working. rather than using .net MAUI Web authenticator use a regular webview and follow this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization.
Then once you select your google account it will redirect you to this url that contains the jwt "{function_app}/.auth/login/done#token={your token}". and use this token to make requests to the function app by sending it in the headers 'X-ZUMO-AUTH'
